# How to compare the current row with the next row in NgFor

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to compare the current row with the next row

Here's my code :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of my_tab; let i=index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="c.id != my_tab[i+1].id">
    //do_something
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

but it doesn't work !

Comment: It could be something with the `<ng-container>` built-in component. If you do not want to use a `<div>` tag for a display property reason, I would suggest using a`<template>` tag.  See: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp

Comment: Try `<ng-container *ngFor="let c of my_tab; let i=index">
  <ng-template *ngIf="c.id != my_tab[i+1].id">
    //do_something
  </ng-template>
</ng-container>`

Comment: i tried <ng-template> but it doesn't work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved the problem :

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let c of my_tab; let i=index">
  <ng-container *ngIf="c.id != my_tab[i+1]?.id">
    //do_something
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tried reproduce your code, it worked.

```
my_tab = [{id:1, name:'C'},{id:2, name:'A'}, {id:2, name:'A'}, {id:3, name:'A'}];


<div *ngFor="let c of my_tab; let i=index">
  <div *ngIf="c.id != my_tab[i+1].id">
    not same
  </div>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-index-next-last